# Different server based on port number

Tags: dns, port

I currently have a VPS setup with a Minecraft server on it running on port 25565.
I also want to have a blog for my server using Tumblr which means that'll need port 80.

The problem I find is I can't have my domain's A record point to both Tumblr and the VPS as they're both different servers(IP addresses).

Comment: Hi OmgImAlexis, welcome to SuperUser! This question doesn't seem very well thought out, doesn't really show what you've tried or researched, and therefore, will probably not yield great answers. Can you [edit] your question to include more details about what you're looking for, what you've tried, router model, whether all systems are inside your network or outside on the Internet, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just set it up in your router's port forwarding or use a proxy, depending on whether your machines are behind NAT or not.

Comment: Hi David, can you expand a bit on this? It's a very basic answer, even for a very basic question...

Comment: It's very hard to give a specific answer to such a generic question.

Comment: I know, but it hit the LQ queue... At least reference to what port forwarding does maybe... And I'll leave a comment for the OP

Comment: I've updated the question. I hope that explains it well enough.

Comment: Your machines are not behind NAT, so you can use a proxy. The VPS could be the proxy. Alternatively, just use different names inside your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a subdomain for the minecraft server with a new A record for the different IP address.

Comment: I know I can use a CNAME record and use a sub-domain but that's not what I want.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a CNAME record. The way you are trying to solve this problem is the wrong back to go about it.

Comment: Even if it isn't a CNAME it's still a subdomain. I know there's a way to do it with both servers using the root domain as I've seen it with other servers, I just don't know how.

Comment: They probably had it running on the same server with 2 different ports.

Comment: No, two different servers.